Kafka Retention Settings - Delete from queue, if all consumer groups consumed a topic
Lets say I have a kafka Queue, and a topic named TOPIC, and I have two consumer groups CONSUMER1 and CONSUMER2. and I have added 1000 data in TOPIC.
Consumer1 has consumer 800 data and CONSUMER2 has consumed 750 data. Is there a setting to delete all consumed logs to a particular offset, if all consumer groups has consumed the data(i.e, reached the offset) or Can i run a retention schedule and delete 750 data from the topic?

Possible retention settings are as below, see here

log.retention.hours
log.retention.bytes
log.retention.ms

You can delete up to an offset, from the command line, with kafka-delete-records-sh

No - kafka doesn't have any configuration for deleting individual records or a TTL and it has no relation to the consumers
Kafka's LogCleaner operates on log segments. A segment defaults to 1Gb of data, which could be hundreds of thousands of records (default max record size is 1MB)
